# The specified container does not exist (Azure)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Code below works. But when i'm trying to delete blob from container i`m getting exception "The specified container does not exist":

```
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("files-for-uploading/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(config["AzureWebJobsStorage"],
            out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
        {
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(HttpClientFactory.Create());
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = 
            blobClient.GetContainerReference(config["ContainerForFileUploading"]);
            DeleteFilesFromBlob(container, name, log);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Delete function:

```
private static void DeleteFilesFromBlob(CloudBlobContainer container, string blobName, ILogger log)
{
    CloudBlob file = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
    file.DeleteIfExists();
}
```

And it delete works when i'm running it in Visual Studio, but does not work in azure. Very strange.

Comment: please elaborate, what you mean with "it does not work in Azure". Azure is a huge platform.

Comment: What's the name of the blob container specified in `ContainerForFileUploading`? Can you check if the blob container exists in your storage account?

Comment: ContainerForFileUploading - this is name of my variable from local.settings.json and configuration tab of azure function in azure

Comment: @AndrewYanchak did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to GetBlobReference should be the name of the blob and not the fileUrl.

The following code Im using myself and it works.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> delete(string blobName)
    {
        string blobstorageconnection = _configuration.GetValue<string>("blobstorage");
        string blobContainer = _configuration.GetValue<string>("blobcontainer");

        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobstorageconnection);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainer);
        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobName);
        await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();



        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @AndrewYanchak please elaborate, what you mean with "it does not work in Azure". Im using the this code in an Azure App Service and it works without any problems.

Comment: you created external service on Asp .Net Core and use it, but i do not. I uploaded function to azure, like you said, in an Azure App Service and delete does not work(